# startAfter does not work with a doc ref made with path

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a React app with firebase as  its backend. I need to retrieve some data from firestore, and to avoid getting all the data at once, I considered limiting the number of results and storing the last returned result from the query in localStorage, so that I can use `startAfter(lastDoc)` in subsequent queries.
However, it turns out that you cannot properly stringify this lastDoc and thus I cannot store it in localStorage. So I thought of storing `path` property and then later using it to create a `doc` ref. I do these things in functions `fetchingFirstTime()` and `fetchingNextTime()` respectively.

```js
import { collection, query, doc, getDocs, orderBy, startAfter } from "firebase/firestore";

let lastDoc = undefined;

async function fetchingFirstTime() {
  try {
    const ref = collection(db, "mycollection")
    const q = query(ref, limitTo(1))
    const data = await getDocs(q);
    lastDoc = data.docs[data.docs.length - 1];
    // cannot strore this document in localStorage, so storing it's path
    lastDoc = lastDoc.ref.path;
    localStorage.setItem("lastDocPath", lastDoc);
  } catch {
    console.log("Something went wrong")
  }
}

async function fetchingNextTime() {
  try {
    const storedDocRefPath = localStorage.getItem("lastDocRef");
    const storedDocRef = doc(db, storedDocRefPath);

    const q = query(ref, orderBy("createdAt"), startAfter(doc1))
    const data = await getDocs(q);
    console.log(data)
  } catch {
    console.log("Something went wront")
  }
}
```

The problem is that the `data` in fetchingNextTime() has an empty array of result, which means that this query is not running properly. I have tried a lot of things but nothing seems to work, I would really appretiate if someone can help me out with this issue.
Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible types you can pass to `startAfter`:

- A `DocumentSnapshot` of the document to start after.
- The field values of the document to start after.

Neither of these matches with what you are doing (passing the document path), which is why your approach won't work.

If you're passing the field values, the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#startafter) says to:

> The field values to start this query after, **in order of the query's order by**.

So you'll want to pass the value of `createdAt`, and the document ID (to ensure you start after the right document, even when there are multiple documents with the same value for `createdAt`).